# Testing Memcached connection

Tags: python, django, memcached

I want to run a basic service which shows the status of various other services on the system (i.e. Mongo, Redis, Memcached, etc).

For Memcached, I thought that I might do something like this:

```
from django.core.cache import cache 

host, name = cache._cache._get_server('test')
```

This seems to return a host and an arbitrary string.  Does the host object confirm that I'm connecting to Memcached successfully?

I know that the returned host object has a `connect()` method. I'm slightly scared to open a new connection in production environment and I don't have an easy Dev setup to test that method. I assume that it's in one of the Python Memcached libraries, but I'm not sure which one is relevant here.

Can I just use the `_get_server` method to test Memecached connection success, or should I use the connect method?

Comment: I'm confused by what your actual question is.

Comment: I had to read this 3 times over before I got what you were asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various things you could monitor, like memcache process up, memcache logs moving etc. that don't require network connectivity. Next level of test would be to see that you can open a socket at the memcache port. But the real test is of course to set and get a value from memcache. For that kind of testing I would probably just use the python-memcached package directly to make the connection and set and get values.